# Will a Greek Orthodox priest in America marry a couple who haven't civilly registered the marriage?

Tags: eastern-orthodox, marriage, united-states

A senior citizen couple I know were married in a Greek Orthodox church ceremony without ever obtaining a marriage license. The priest agreed to do this. Is this allowed by the Church? I know several Greek Orthodox people and we have never heard of such a thing. The couple reside together but keep separate finances and the wife retained her own name.

Comment: Wouldn’t  the church be the real authority for marriage and not the state?

Comment: I know Catholic priests who will, just for the reasons mentioned.